# не удалось подключиться к базе template1

Tags: postgresql

Хочу использовать `postgresql` на `windows`. Установил `PostgreSQL-11.1-1` и `pgadmin4-3.6-x86`. Пишу команду для создания базы данных `createdb store` в консоле и мне выдает ошибку `createdb: не удалось подключиться к базе template1: FATAL:  role "user1" does not exist`. В чем может быть проблема?